# Error referencing cells in a table after adding table

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm writing  a routine that builds a TOC in a presentation based on the existence of 'Section Divider Slides' (Custom Layout Slide).  When I try to build the TOC per se in a table that I add on a 'Table of Contents' custom slide, trying to set the .cell values I get an 'Object does not support this property or method'.  I think it may have to do with the way I add the table and reference it but I can't figure it out.

The problematic code is just before the pseudo code for the rest of the routine starts.  Bare in mind it's a first run so it may not be polished.

Thanks in advance.

```
   Option Explicit
   Sub BuildTOC()
   
   Dim oSlide As slide
   Dim i As Single
   Dim myCol As Collection
   Dim myColDividers As Collection
       
   Dim UserInput As Variant
   Dim InputQuestion As String
   Dim SectionCount As Single
   Dim DeleteTOCs As Long
   Dim TOCSlide As Single
   Dim SlideNum As Single
   Dim TitleText As String
   
   Dim oTable As Shape
   Dim tRows As Long
   Dim tCols As Long
   Dim tLeft As Single
   Dim tTop As Single
   Dim tWidth As Single
   Dim tHeight As Single
   Dim tCol1Width As Single
   Dim tCol2Width As Single
   Dim tCol3Width As Single
   
   
   
   Set myCol = New Collection
   Set myColDividers = New Collection
   
   If ActivePresentation.Slides.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
   
   '' Get number of dividers
   SectionCount = 0
   For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
      Debug.Print i & ": " & ActivePresentation.Slides(i).CustomLayout.Name
      If ActivePresentation.Slides(i).CustomLayout.Name = "Section Divider" Then
         SectionCount = SectionCount + 1
      End If
   Next i
   
   Debug.Print "==================================="
   '' loop through slides and add TOC layouts to collection
   For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
      Debug.Print i & ": " & ActivePresentation.Slides(i).CustomLayout.Name
      If ActivePresentation.Slides(i).CustomLayout.Name = "Table of Contents" Then
         myCol.Add CStr(i), CStr(i)
      End If
   Next i
   
   '' if no TOCs found, exit
   If myCol.Count > 0 Then
   '' Delete TOCs found
      DeleteTOCs = MsgBox("This will delete all existing Tables of Contents." & vbNewLine & "Continue?", vbYesNo)
         If vbYes Then
            
            i = 0
            For i = myCol.Count To 1 Step -1
               ActivePresentation.Slides(val(myCol.item(i))).Delete
               Debug.Print "Delete TOC on slide " & myCol.item(i)
            Next
         End If
   End If
   
   ' Select position for TOC
   ' Keeping looping until we get a valid answer
   
   InputQuestion = "Insert TOC before which slide number?" & vbNewLine & _
                   "Please input a number between 1 and " & ActivePresentation.Slides.Count & "."
   Do
       'Retrieve answer from the user
     UserInput = InputBox(InputQuestion, "Table of Contents Position")
       'Check if user selected cancel button
     If StrPtr(UserInput) = 0 Then Exit Sub
      'Check if user clicked OK without entering a value
      If UserInput = vbNullString Then
         MsgBox ("You must enter a value or click on Cancel")
      End If
   Loop While UserInput < 1 Or UserInput > ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
   
   ' Insert it
   Set oSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(UserInput, GetLayout("Table of Contents"))
   TOCSlide = oSlide.SlideIndex
   
   Debug.Print "==================================="
   '' loop through slides and add TOC layouts to collection
   For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
      Debug.Print i & ": " & ActivePresentation.Slides(i).CustomLayout.Name
      If ActivePresentation.Slides(i).CustomLayout.Name = "Table of Contents" Then
         myColDividers.Add CStr(i), CStr(i)
      End If
   Next i
   
   Debug.Print "==================================="
   '' Loop through slides and collect dividers
   For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
      Debug.Print i & ": " & ActivePresentation.Slides(i).CustomLayout.Name
      If ActivePresentation.Slides(i).CustomLayout.Name = "Section Divider" Then
         myColDividers.Add CStr(i), CStr(i)
      End If
   Next i
   
   
   
   ' set Rows and Columns
   tRows = SectionCount
   tCols = 3
   
   ' Table dimensions
   tLeft = CentimetersToPoints(9.09)
   tTop = CentimetersToPoints(6.13)
   tWidth = CentimetersToPoints(22.74)
   tHeight = 24 ''CentimetersToPoints(11.72)
   
   tCol1Width = CentimetersToPoints(2.7)
   tCol2Width = CentimetersToPoints(17.4)
   tCol3Width = CentimetersToPoints(2.7)
   
   '' Create table
   Set oSlide = Nothing
   Set oSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(TOCSlide)
   
   Call DeleteTablesFromSlide(oSlide)
   
   Set oTable = oSlide.Shapes.AddTable(tRows, tCols, tLeft, tTop, tWidth, tHeight)
   
   With oTable.Table
   
      .Columns(1).Width = tCol1Width
      .Columns(2).Width = tCol2Width
      .Columns(3).Width = tCol3Width
      
   
   Debug.Print "======================================"
   i = 0
   For i = 1 To myColDividers.Count
      SlideNum = val(myColDividers.item(i))
      TitleText = ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes.Title.textFrame.textRange.text
      If ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes.HasTitle Then
         If Len(TitleText) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print SlideNum & ": " & TitleText
            .cell(i, 1) = i
            .cell(i, 2) = TitleText
            .cell(i, 3) = SlideNum
         End If
      Else
         Debug.Print "No title"
         .cell(i, 1) = i
         .cell(i, 2) = " No title"
         .cell(i, 3) = SlideNum
      End If
   Next i
   
   End With
   
   '   For RowNum = 1 To SectionCount
   '      .cell(RowNum, 1) = RowNum
   '      .
   '      With shp.Table.cell(RowNum, 1).Shape.textFrame.textRange.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink
   '         .SubAddress = .cell(RowNum, 1).Shape.textFrame.textRange.text
   '         .TextToDisplay = .cell(RowNum, 1).Shape.textFrame.textRange.text
   '      End With
   
   ''     'slide number col
   ''     With shp.Table.cell(i - 1, 2).Shape.textFrame.textRange.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink
   ''         .SubAddress = shp.Table.cell(i - 1, 2).Shape.textFrame.textRange.text
   ''         .TextToDisplay = shp.Table.cell(i - 1, 2).Shape.textFrame.textRange.text
   ''     End With
   ''Next i
   
   '' Format TOC
   ''
   ''
   ''Next
   ''paste Table
   
   ''
   ''
   ''i = 0
   ''x = 0
   ''Set mycoll = Nothing
   ''
   ''For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
   ''
   ''     If oSlide.layout = divider
   ''    Add to collection
   ''
   ''Find the table
   ''
   ''For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
   ''
   ''''
   ''End If
   ''
   ''    Oslide table delete
   ''    End If
   ''Next
   ''
   
   
   ''
   ''For i = 1 to slide count
   ''    If slide(i) layout = divider
   ''    Add to mycoll
   ''Next
   ''i = 0
   ''
   ''For i = 1 To mycoll.Count
   ''slide (i)
   ''Paste Table
   ''Format row i to highlight row position
   ''Next
   
   End Sub
   
   
   Public Function GetLayout( _
       LayoutName As String, _
       Optional ParentPresentation As Presentation = Nothing) As CustomLayout
       Dim oLayout As CustomLayout
       
       If ParentPresentation Is Nothing Then
           Set ParentPresentation = ActivePresentation
       End If
   
       For Each oLayout In ParentPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
           If oLayout.Name = LayoutName Then
               Set GetLayout = oLayout
               Exit For
           End If
       Next
   End Function
   
   
   Public Function DeleteTablesFromSlide(mySlide As PowerPoint.slide) As Long
     Dim lCntr As Long
     Dim lTables As Long
     ' Count backwards when deleting items from a collection
     For lCntr = mySlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
       With mySlide.Shapes(lCntr)
         Select Case .Type
           Case msoTable: .Delete: lTables = lTables + 1 ' msoTable = 19
           Case msoPlaceholder ' msoPlaceholder = 19
             If .PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoTable Then .Delete: lTables = lTables + 1
         End Select
       End With
     Next
     DeleteTablesFromSlide = lTables
   End Function
```

Comment: You already have the answer to your question. The code you have commented out shows how to work with table cells.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Thank you.  I'm still getting an error particularly in the code section:

Comment: You need to be specific: which line gives you an error?

Comment: I get the error at             .cell(i, 1) = i
            .cell(i, 2) = TitleText
            .cell(i, 3) = SlideNum

Comment: It will help you a great deal if you learn to use 1) IntelliSense; 2) the Object Browser; 3) online help. All of these would point you to the answer, as would looking at the first part of the code you have commented out which shows how to work with table cells correctly:  `.Cell(row, col).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text`

Comment: My bad, thanks @TimothyRylatt

Answer (score 0):

As @timothyrylatt pointed out, my mistake was in how I was trying to manipulate the cells.

Instead of:
.cell(row,col) = Text

it should be:

.Cell(row, col).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Text